# Указатели. Ошибка

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() {

    char *str = "Hello";

}
```

значение типа `const char` нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа `char`.

В видео уроке который я смотрел, написано абсолютно так же. В чём проблема?

Comment: Не смотрите видео уроков. Кроме того, заявленная ошибка не соответствует коду. Тут происходит попытка инициализации сущности типа `char *` значением типа `char const [6]`. А такое преобразование во-первых обычно не нужно, во-вторых требует `const_cast`.

Answer (score 5):

Проблема в том, что, строго говоря, литерал строки - константен, и компилятор может, например, разместить его в памяти только для чтения.

Если бы было можно написать

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

то можно было бы его изменить, например, с помощью

```
str[0] = '!';
```

что является нарушением. Так что используйте

```
const char *str = "Hello";
```

или

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

(в последнем случае литерал строки копируется в изменяемый массив `str`).

Comment: Запись `char *str = "Hello";` сама по себе является не валидной.

Comment: @VTT Естественно. Если я буду пояснять, что писать что-нибудь типа `int i = "Hello"*2.5;` нельзя, потому что то-то и то-то - то что, обязательно надо будет подчеркнуть, что само по себе это выражение не является валидным?

Comment: Разумеется, а то по вашему ответу получается что написать `char *str = "Hello";` можно, а проблема в том, что память окажется только для чтения и ее потом можно будет изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Наличие реальной проблемы в данном случае зависит от компилятора. Если используете gcc, то даже можно ее испытать.

```
$ cat 1.cpp
int main() {
    char *str = "Hello";
    str[0] = '!'; // собственно, пытаемся поменять содержимое
    return 0;
}
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ g++ -o 1 1.cpp
1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cpp:2:17: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     char *str = "Hello";
             ^
$ ./1 # запускаем и получаем ошибку сегментации
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

В [статье на вики про ошибку сегментации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) как раз нечто похожее и обсуждается. Такая ошибка возникает, когда программа пытается что-то сделать с памятью, что ей нельзя. В данном случае - программа пытается изменить содержимое памяти, доступной ей только для чтения.

Тем не менее, не во всех случаях это приводит к проблемам, но предпочтительно не пытаться менять то, что имеет квалификатор `const`.